# Find all complex numbers $a_i$ such that $\prod\limits_{j\neq i=1}^k \ (a_i-a_j)^n=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

$n>1$ is fixed.
Find all complex numbers $a_1,\dots,a_k\;$ such that $\prod\limits_{j\neq i=1}^k \ (a_i-a_j)^n=1.$
What I did until now was solving for $k=3,2$ that it was not hard.

Comment: If $n=2$, then why $\{0, i\}$ is not such a set? $(0-i)^2(i-0)^2 = 1$.

Comment: For $n=k=2$, the solutions are $a_2 = a_1 \pm 1$, $a_1$ arbitrary.

Comment: sorry for the typo

Comment: $a_i$ are invariant under shifts and scaling. To account for shifts we'll let $\delta_i=a_i-a_{i+1}$. So the problem reduces to characterizing all $\delta_i$ such that $\delta_i(\delta_i+\delta_{i+1})...(\delta_i+\delta_{i+1}+...+\delta_{k+i-1}) = $ some nth root of unity for each i and the indices are taken mod $k$.